# jQuery function to check next div is visible and hide current div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to write a jQuery function that will fire on a new `div` being made visible elsewhere in the script. The function will then hide only the `div` (with a different classname) immediately preceding the current one.

So far I have the following:

```
$(".next-question-button").on('click', function (e) {
    if ($('.question-bar').next().css('display', 'block');) {
        $(this).('.question-bar').hide();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="question-bar">Question 1</div>
<div class="question-div">
    <div class="next-question-div">
        <button type="button" class="next-question-button">Next Question</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="question-bar">Question 2</div>
<div class="question-div">
    <div class="next-question-div">
        <button type="button" class="next-question-button">Next Question</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="question-bar">Question 3</div>
<div class="question-div">
    <div class="next-question-div">
        <button type="button" class="next-question-button">Next Question</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My thinking was that if the next question button is clicked the new `div` would be made visible and then the 'div.question-bar' that immediately precedes the new `div` would be hidden?

The new `div` is a sibling to the `div.question-bar`, but there are several of both through out the document. So when a the new `div` is made visible I just want the previous `div` (with class name `question-bar`) to be hidden?

What's the best way to approach this? Thanks in advance

Comment: There is syntax error in your code.It must be .css('display', 'block')

Comment: The correct syntax could be `if ($('.question-bar').next().css('display') === 'block')`

Comment: Just edited the syntax to reflect what it currently is, and not working. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @AlexChar is right. You're *Setting* the `dispay` to `block` in your `if` statement, rather than checking it - plus, I don't think your existing code would work anyway, as you're using a `;` after the function. Have you tried Alex's suggestion?

Comment: To confirm: putting a `;` inside an `if` gives `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`  (it's not the same as `if () ; ` which means do nothing )

Comment: @ManishJangir / @AlaxChar - read the process, the requirement *is* to show the next div (so the syntax is kind-of correct).  The `if` is not required.  It's very strange :)

Comment: @freedomn-m Earlier there was a syntax mistake. Thats why I wrote. He might have correct it

Comment: @ManishJangir that's correct, I've edited the syntax

Comment: @ManishJangir my mistake, your correction was correct, it was the `css("display") == "block"` that's wrong.

Comment: @AlexChar - read the process, the requirement is to show the next div (so the syntax is kind-of correct). The if is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you'll find on many SO questions, `.next` gives the very next element, regardless of its class.  If you add a class, it's still the next one, but only if that next one matches the filter otherwise null - it doesn't continue until it finds a matching element, that would be `.nextAll(".class").first()`.

This also applies to `.prev`

So, if you're using .next/.prev, then there's no need to worry about "but there are several of both through out the document".

Your current process is:

- click button
- find next div, show that div
- from that div (the next one), find the previous one and hide it

you already know the previous one as it's the one you've just clicked the button within.

So instead:

- click button
- hide the div*s* for the button
- show the next one*s*

ie, for this html:

```
<div class="question-bar">Question 1</div>
<div class="question-div">
    <div class="next-question-div">
        <button type="button" class="next-question-button">Next Question</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="question-bar">Question 2</div>
<div class="question-div">
    <div class="next-question-div">
            <button type="button" class="next-question-button">Next Question</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

you get:

```
$(".next-question-button").on("click", function() {

    // get the container for this button
    var div = $(this).closest(".question-div");

    // hide this container as we're moving on to the next question
    div.hide();

    // also hide the question 1 bar
    div.prev().hide();

    // show the next question bar and div
    // .next() is applied at the .question-div level so gives the next .question-bar (no filter required)
    div.next().show();

    // it goes bar-div-bar-div so at the first bar, the second bar is next/next
    // this will *not* work: div.next(".question-div")
    div.next().next().show();

    // an alternative that will work and may be better than .next.next
    //div.nextAll(".question-div").first().show();
});
```

where `.closest` finds the containing question bar.

Comment: thanks for your answer and explanation. I feel I have a better grasp of how the next function works. I think my issue is that I'm integrating it into another script, and think there maybe so conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```js
$(function() {
  $(".next-question-button").on('click', function() {
    $parent = $(this).parents('.question-div');
    $parent.hide();
    $parent.prev('.question-bar').hide();

    $parent.next('.question-bar').show();
    $parent.next('.question-bar').next('.question-div').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="question-bar">Question 1</div>
<div class="question-div">
  <div class="next-question-div">
    <button type="button" class="next-question-button">Next Question</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="question-bar">Question 2</div>
<div class="question-div">
  <div class="next-question-div">
    <button type="button" class="next-question-button">Next Question</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="question-bar">Question 3</div>
<div class="question-div">
  <div class="next-question-div">
    <button type="button" class="next-question-button">Next Question</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is close to what I'm going for so thanks. I should have been clearer in my qu however. I'm looking for just the '.question-bar' previous to the current '.question-div' being shown to be hidden. So when a '.question-div' is being displayed, the question bar before is not. When you move on to the next 'question-div' the '.question-bar' that was just hidden is shown again - if that makes any sense...

Comment: thanks but again I wanted all question bars to be shown apart from the one previous to the question-div being displayed at the time